# How to use jq package to parse name and id from json?

Tags: jq

I have an output that i am getting in this format :-

```
[
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "my-name",
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "my-name2",
    "id": "456"
  },
  {
    "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
    "name": "my-name3",
    "id": "789"
  }
]
```

How can i parse the name and id using jq?

I tried to use `[].name`

but i get `curl: (23) Failed writing body (320 != 1338)`

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using jq, then put a dot `.` before the brackets: `jq '.[].name'` for instance. But are you using jq though? Your error seems to having been reported by curl.

Comment: The error message mentions `curl`, but your question doesn't.  Please clarify.

Comment: @pmf Thanks. That worked. You add that as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: @peak I got the output from a curl command and then i tried to parse it. Instead i first stored the output in an output.json and then did what pmf suggested. lt worked.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever Don't bother, you've got your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to mention the relevant error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:17): Cannot index array with string "name"
```

The program should be

```
.[].name
```

Because you provided an incorrect program to `jq`, it exited earlier than it normally would. This caused the pipe between `curl` and `jq` to close, which cause `curl` to become unable to write to the pipe, which caused `curl` to emit the error message you did provide.

Answer (score 0):

Demo
https://jqplay.org/s/nolGbk3sD1

Use filter

```
.[] | .name, .id
```